# LinearLayout not Displaying

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, scrollview

Hi I'm learning Android.

Here is the code for my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.aidsdruginformation.DetailActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="ApprovalStatus"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="FDA-approved"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="ApprovalStatus"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="GDA-approved"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

UI Screen shot:

[image: Screenshot]

How I want my UI to look:
[image: Sample UI]
**Why is the second `LinearLayout` not showing?**
Am I doing something wrong?
**While using `layout_width` should the parent element have a fixed dimension?**
Please advice..

Link to my Repo:
https://github.com/MukundPradeep/AidsDrugInformation

Comment: use `android:fillViewport="true"` on the ScrollView

Comment: above comment is answer.

Comment: I have added this and set android:weightSum="2" to my parent LinearLayout.. The second inner LinearLayout is still not displaying

Comment: show screenshot, how you want ?

Comment: Have edited with UI needed.. The horizontal elements must be aligned.. And the page must be scrollable.. I do not want to use a ListView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going through my Repo,

I figured that the `activity_detail.xml` under the `layout v-17` folder was being used by the framework because the `android:textAlignment="center"` attribute I have used is only available for API 17+. My target SDK is 23.
Therefore the layout I posted(under `layout` directory) would only show on devices running versions of Android less than 17.

If you are planning to use the above mentioned attribute, please make sure you implement your layout changes in all the layout folders generated for different APIs.

Thanks everyone for trying to help me out.

Comment: yes yes . thats the problem .Sorry for delay . check my edited answer (comments)

Comment: ahaha.. saw and commented there too :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use **[android:fillViewport](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport)**

> Defines whether the scrollview should stretch its content to fill the
>   viewport.
>
> Must be a boolean value, either "true" or "false".

You should try with below approach . make `LinearLayout` as root .

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">
       // Your Staff
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Tried that with no luck.. Link to my Repo: https://github.com/MukundPradeep/AidsDrugInformation Can you please take a look at it?

Comment: @MukundPradeep okay .wait

Comment: @MukundPradeep remove .at first copy `activity_detail.xml` then remove  `activity_detail.xml`v17 .Finally two xmls deleted then paste `activity_detail.xml` .then clean-restart.

Comment: problem for `activity_detail` and `activity_detail`v17

Comment: Thanks.. I figured it out some time back

Answer (score 1):

Try, added some attribute to ScrollView ,

> android:fillViewport="true",
>           android:isScrollContainer="true"

add LinearLayout as parent of ScrollView

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="ApprovalStatus"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="FDA-approved"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
            </LinearLayout >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="ApprovalStatus"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="GDA-approved"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
            </LinearLayout >

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="8" />
        </LinearLayout >
    </ScrollView >
</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: and yes, you must have data to scroll

Comment: Amit.. I used your exact same code and still the second Layout is not showing..l

Comment: than you have done something else wrong because this layout show two linearlayout with scrrolview

Comment: Do you have any idea where else I might be making a mistake? Link to Repo: https://github.com/MukundPradeep/AidsDrugInformation

Comment: try some simple code with android:weightSum and watch is that showing properly ?

Comment: is this a row file of Listview in 
activity_main.xml ?

Comment: change that Listview to 
**<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar"
        android:background="@drawable/listshape"
        android:entries="@array/list" />** in activity_main.xml

Comment: Changed and tried.. No change to detail activity.. How will changing the main activity help fix the detail activity?

Answer (score 0):

Just give parent linear layout this attribute:

`android:weightSum="2"` then your both child linear layout are Shown on Screen.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your code and it is showing

try this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context="com.example.android.aidsdruginformation.DetailActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="ApprovalStatus"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="FDA-approved"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="ApprovalStatus"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="GDA-approved"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

OUTPUT
[image]

Comment: Tried this using android:fillViewport="true".. Still not displaying on my phone

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.aidsdruginformation.DetailActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="ApprovalStatus"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="FDA-approved"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="ApprovalStatus"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="GDA-approved"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

You are giving the first layout weight as 1. Which will take the full height of screen. You can divide it. But also inside scrollview if you give weight then what is the use of that scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

check this .and make it as right  if its helpful.

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="20dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        >


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="Now book a ride at 6Rs/km with uber go"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />




            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="7/11 supermarket get special discounts today only"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />






    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/l1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/l2">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="10% discount on all meals"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />




            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="Clearance sale upto 40% off"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />





    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="201dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/l2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        >

       <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="Starbucks coffee try our special new mocha latte for a limited period discount"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

               <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="Buy 2 get 1 free*"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
     </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your two linear layouts with another linear layout with vertical orientation(as shown in the many comments). In your case both the linear layouts are overlapping each other so you see just one.
Unless it has enough items to scroll, it can not be scrollable.